# Issue in HTML table formatting

Tags: html, css

I am making a html page in which i am using table for the some items. as below image shows:
[image: Sample image]

The code for the this table is as bellow:

```
<table border="2">
 <tbody><tr>
  <td width="50">
    <b>
        <span style="color:red">
            Id
        </span>
    </b>
  </td>
  <td width="150">
    <b>
        <span style="color:red">
            Product Name
        </span>
    </b>
  </td>
  <td width="150">
    <b>
        <span style="color:red">
            Product Price
        </span>
    </b>
  </td>
  <td width="50"></td>
 </tr>

      <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>Lamps</td>
   <td><i>$3.5</i></td>
   <td> <a href="/app_name/editpage.htm?id=1&amp;prodname=Lamps&amp;prodprice=3.5">Edit</a></td>
   <td><a href="/app_name/deleteprod.htm?id=1&amp;prodname=Lamps&amp;prodprice=3.5">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>

      <tr>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>Table</td>
   <td><i>$75.29</i></td>
   <td> <a href="/app_name/editpage.htm?id=2&amp;prodname=Table&amp;prodprice=75.29">Edit</a></td>
   <td><a href="/app_name/deleteprod.htm?id=2&amp;prodname=Table&amp;prodprice=75.29">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>

      <tr>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>Chair</td>
   <td><i>$22.81</i></td>
   <td> <a href="/app_name/editpage.htm?id=3&amp;prodname=Chair&amp;prodprice=22.81">Edit</a></td>
   <td><a href="/app_name/deleteprod.htm?id=3&amp;prodname=Chair&amp;prodprice=22.81">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>

     </tbody></table>
```

Now my problem is that why the line of the header is not completed so how to do it? I am new to html and css and I am learning it. Please need guidance. Thank you.

Comment: Presentational **NESTED** markup, MY EYES BURN!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have more columns in the bottom rows. 
There are many solutions:

One (not so pretty) way to solve your problem would be to add more cells in the top row.

```
<td width="50">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="50">&nbsp;</td>
```

( http://jsfiddle.net/tCrRG/ )

Or, try to take a look at `colspan` and `rowspan`:

```
<td width="150" colspan="3">
    <b>
        <span style="color:red">
            Product Price
        </span>
    </b>
  </td>
```

( http://jsfiddle.net/tCrRG/1/ )

Or, add just **one** cell in the top row with colspan:

```
<td colspan="2">
    &nbsp;
</td>
```

( http://jsfiddle.net/tCrRG/2/ )

Answer (score 1):

The only put three cells in the header row when there are five cells in the subsequent rows. To make the third header column fill out to the right, use **colspan=3**:

```
<td width="150" colspan=3>
    <b>
        <span style="color:red">
            Product Price
        </span>
    </b>
  </td>
```

On a side note, as noted by others above, it's not good practice to use inline styling or nest style markup. Try looking into using a CSS class for your column headers:

HTML:

```
<td class="header_cell">
    Product Price
</td>
```

CSS:

```
.header_cell {
    width:150px;
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Empty cells are no be displayed and you could use `space` or `&nbsp;` html entity to put some empty content.

You could use `colspan` attribute to make the cell extend for 2 columns.

```
<table border="2">
 <tbody><tr>
  <td width="50">
    <b>
        <span style="color:red">
            Id
        </span>
    </b>
  </td>
  <td width="150">
    <b>
        <span style="color:red">
            Product Name
        </span>
    </b>
  </td>
  <td width="150">
    <b>
        <span style="color:red">
            Product Price
        </span>
    </b>
  </td>
  <td width="50" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>

      <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>Lamps</td>
   <td><i>$3.5</i></td>
   <td> <a href="/app_name/editpage.htm?id=1&amp;prodname=Lamps&amp;prodprice=3.5">Edit</a></td>
   <td><a href="/app_name/deleteprod.htm?id=1&amp;prodname=Lamps&amp;prodprice=3.5">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>

      <tr>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>Table</td>
   <td><i>$75.29</i></td>
   <td> <a href="/app_name/editpage.htm?id=2&amp;prodname=Table&amp;prodprice=75.29">Edit</a></td>
   <td><a href="/app_name/deleteprod.htm?id=2&amp;prodname=Table&amp;prodprice=75.29">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>

      <tr>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>Chair</td>
   <td><i>$22.81</i></td>
   <td> <a href="/app_name/editpage.htm?id=3&amp;prodname=Chair&amp;prodprice=22.81">Edit</a></td>
   <td><a href="/app_name/deleteprod.htm?id=3&amp;prodname=Chair&amp;prodprice=22.81">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>

     </tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want an empty cell above the Edit/Delete links and not increasing the Product Price cell.

Therefore try a colspan=2 in your empty cell

```
<td colspan="2" width="50"></td>
```

instead

```
<td width="50"></td>
```

in your first row.

Answer (score 1):

I've improved your code quite a bit.

```
<style type="text/css">
    table {
        width: 400px;
    }
    table th{
        font-weight: bold;
        color: red;
    }
    table tr td:nth-child(3) {
        font-style: italic;
    }
</style>
<table border="2">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Product Price</th>
            <th colspan="2">Actions</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Lamps</td>
            <td>$3.5</td>
            <td><a href="/app_name/editpage.htm?id=1&amp;prodname=Lamps&amp;prodprice=3.5">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a href="/app_name/deleteprod.htm?id=1&amp;prodname=Lamps&amp;prodprice=3.5">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Table</td>
            <td>$75.29</td>
            <td><a href="/app_name/editpage.htm?id=2&amp;prodname=Table&amp;prodprice=75.29">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a href="/app_name/deleteprod.htm?id=2&amp;prodname=Table&amp;prodprice=75.29">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Chair</td>
            <td>$22.81</td>
            <td><a href="/app_name/editpage.htm?id=3&amp;prodname=Chair&amp;prodprice=22.81">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a href="/app_name/deleteprod.htm?id=3&amp;prodname=Chair&amp;prodprice=22.81">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

### Explanation

- Removed the used of presentational markup. Replaced with a `<style>` element.
- Replace the header cells with appropriate `<th>` elements.
- Added an `Actions` header with a `colspan="2"`, which means it will strech for 2 columns (filling up the remaining space).

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. I am really grateful for you kind effort